# Whiptail inputbox cancel not working

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, whiptail

I've created a loop to go through some Virtual Machine setup functions for a new user, which goes through things like adding a hostname, ip address, etc.  However, if I click the 'Cancel' button within any of the whiptail windows, it just moves on to the next whiptail element in the loop.  How can I set it up to cancel the loop and go back to the main menu window if `Cancel` is selected instead?

```
while true
do

OPTION=$(whiptail --title "Configuration Menu" --menu "Choose an option" 20 78 10 \
"1"     "Show current configuration." \
"2"     "Setup Wizard." \
...
"0"     "EXIT" 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3)

exitstatus=$?

case "$OPTION" in
 ...
 2)
    # Setup hostname
    HOSTNAME=$(whiptail --inputbox "Hostname" 8 78 `hostname` --title "Serial Number" 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3)
    ...
    # IP address configuration
    IP_CONFIG=$(whiptail --title "Network Configuration" --radiolist "Choose a configuration option" 20 78 10 \
        "DHCP" "Use Dynamic Host Protocol" ON \
        "STATIC" "Configure Static IP" OFF 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3)
     ...
 ;;
esac
```

Here is what the main menu looks like:
[image]

And if when clicking on 'cancel' in the first input box...
[image]

I'm sent to the next whiptail element instead of canceling to the main menu:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ok, figured it out.  I had to wrap each case option in it's own `exitstatus = 0` test:

```
2)
      # Setup serial number
      SERIAL=$(whiptail --inputbox "Serial Number" 8 78 `hostname` --title "Serial Number" 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3)
      exitstatus=$?
      if [ $exitstatus = 0 ]; then
         ...
      else
         break
      fi
      ;;
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `break` which exits a loop. `whiptail` returns 1 on `<Cancel>` selection, so test for that, and `break` if so:

```
OPTION=$(whiptail --title "Configuration Menu" --menu "Choose an option" 20 78 10 \
"1"     "Show current configuration." \
"2"     "Setup Wizard." \
...
"0"     "EXIT" 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3)

exitstatus=$?

[[ "$exitstatus" = 1 ]] && break;
```

Comment: Should I be placing the `$exitstatus =` test in each case option or directly underneath the initial `$exitstatus` variable?

Comment: Underneath the `$exitstatus` should do.

Comment: No, it still progresses to the next window instead of back to the main menu

Comment: Try `echo "$exitstatus"` underneath `$?` and tell me what that returns, please?

Comment: I put this underneath, but there is no file being created: `echo $exitstatus >> test.log`